# Mouse event buggy

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlist, mouselistener

I have the following code for JList. On click for an item in the list it should highlight the selected item. But if I press too fast it wont actually select the next item on list on the first click. How should I solve this?

```
   MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (e.getClickCount() == 1) {


           String selectedItem = (String) jl.getSelectedValue();
           if(selectedItem == "Page One"){
              System.out.print("Page one");
              }
        }
    }
};  
    jl.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On click for an item in the list it should highlight the selected item

This is the default behaviour, so I'm not sure why you are doing this.

> But if I press too fast it wont actually select the next item on list on the first click.

Probably because you aren't generating a `mouseClicked` event. A mouseClicked event is only generated when a mousePressed/mouseReleased event is generated at the same pixel location. Maybe the mouse is moving slightly. Try just adding your code to `mousePressed`.

> but i only want mouse click, even if the user using the arrow key to change it should not happen

That is a terrible UI. The user should control whether they want to use the mouse or keyboard. Advanced users will use the keyboard and beginners will use the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

A `MouseListener` is in appropriate for the task, instead use a [`ListSelectionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionListener.html)

Take a look at [How to write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) and [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details

Comment: so i should just change the mouselistenr to ListSelectionListener?

Comment: That would be my suggestion...make sure you read through the linked tutorials. Selection can change for any number of reasons, not just because of a mouse click

Comment: but i only want mouse click, even if the user using the arrow key to change it should not happen

Comment: The problem you have is not knowing in what order the mouse click might trigger a selection change...

Comment: the thing in the code is working but not very responsive upon clicking too fast

Comment: Clicking to fast will be interrupted as a multiple click, meaning that the if condition of `e.getClickCount() == 1` will ignore them